# How to integrate Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) with Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, adobe, integration, aem

How to integrate Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) website with Salesforce?

How can we seamlessly integrate our Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) website with Salesforce to enhance customer experience and streamline data synchronization? What steps should be taken to leverage AEM connectors effectively, establish robust data mapping, and implement features like Single Sign-On (SSO) for improved accessibility? Additionally, how can we optimize the integration by utilizing APIs for real-time data exchange and enabling marketing automation to enhance lead nurturing and conversion? Seeking guidance on monitoring and continuously optimizing the integration to ensure optimal performance and user satisfaction.

Comment: It is usually helpful to include what have you tried, or specific concerns about what you would implement. This is not the place to get a whole solution design, but of course, you can get community feedback for specific questions or issues.